# How do I remove the file extension from URLs in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Let's say I have a file named `careers.php`, how do I serve this file when they click a link that goes to `http://example.com/careers` without the file extension for both `.html` and `.php` files with **nginx**?

1. Please note that the solution has to account for query strings. For instance, the URL may be `http://example.com/careers?lang=fr`.
2. Also, I'd like the solution to also try subdirectories as well. For instance; if my folder structure on the server is `/views/careers.php`, I want `http://example.com/careers` to still serve `/views/careers.php`.

My current configuration looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/landing-page;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution uses `try_files` with a named location. The existing `location ~ \.php$` block is used to process `.php` files. Also avoid any `if` statements.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ $uri.php last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try_files`:

```
try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
```

Comment: Would `try_files $uril $uri.php /views/$uri.php $uri/ =404;` work for my second point? Also, will this allow for query strings?

Comment: @EdwardMaxedon yes, query strings will be unaffected. For second point take into account that `$uri` will contain leading slash

Comment: I've noticed now instead of processing the file as a .php file, it downloads when I visit the page. Does the `location ~ \.php$` block need to update as well?

Comment: @EdwardMaxedon yes, better make it a named location (like `@php`) and use from root `try_files`

Comment: Adding ` location / {
      if (!-e $request_filename){
          rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
      }
  try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/ =404;
 }` solved the problem I had with my browser downloading the file instead of it processing it as a `.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I feel like this was never perfectly explained or explained using the most simple solution.

Here is an example of how I accomplished this for a React Application served using nginx for my Portfolio Website hosted on Digital Ocean.

When simplified it's super easy to accomplish. The location block should look like this.

Originally my location block was set up like this

```
location /chatgpt-homepage.html {
   root /var/www/myportfoliowebsite.com/html/chatgpt-app-homepage/build;
}
```

What needs to happen is you need to remove the `.html` from your location and add the following underneath your root section of code:

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
```

New Location Block example below:

```
location /chatgpt-homepage {
   root /var/www/myportfoliowebsite.com/html/chatgpt-app-homepage/build;
   try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
}
```